# Bootstrap 4 Tabs with Previous & Next buttons

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm attempting to create some previous and next buttons within a bootstrap 4 tab snippet, but I'm having trouble with the Jquery. More specifically structuring my trigger event or' the path to my trigger event.

I can't seem to figure out the route properly. I'm fairly inexperienced with Jquery so be gentle. ;P

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btnNext').click(function() {
    $('.nav-tabs > .nav-item > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
  });

  $('.btnPrevious').click(function() {
    $('.nav-tabs > .nav-item > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
  });
});
```

You can find a full snippet of what I'm in the process of building here ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erwq5da4/7/));

Many thanks in advance.

-B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the parent of the `active` tab and then `.next()` or `.prev()`. So, the correct jQuery selectors would be...

```
  $('.btnNext').click(function() {
    $('.nav-tabs .active').parent().next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
  });

  $('.btnPrevious').click(function() {
    $('.nav-tabs .active').parent().prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
  });
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/d7X3s15VCS