# Bootstrap Tabs using Next & Previous Buttons for Forms

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am super stuck trying to split a form up in multiple tabs but having issues with the next and previous buttons on the second and third tab.

I want the tabs on top to change state as you would cycle through the tabs by clicking the buttons.

I have created a code pen and if anyone out there knows what I am doing wrong please let me know.

https://codepen.io/austin-simpkins/pen/yLyNLem

```
$('.btnNext').click(function() {
  $('.nav-pills > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function() {
  $('.nav-pills > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `active` link is not the immediate child of `nav-pills`, so remove the child (`>`) selector:

```
$('.btnNext').click(function() {
    $('.nav-pills .active').parent().next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
})

$('.btnPrevious').click(function() {
    $('.nav-pills .active').parent().prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
})
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/pS5at1cWfA)

---

[Bootstrap 4 Tabs with Previous & Next buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655164/bootstrap-4-tabs-with-previous-next-buttons/51655343#51655343)

Comment: Thank you this helped a ton!

Answer (score 3):

The `active` class is being set on the a.nav-link node, so you need to look for the active state of that:

```
$('.btnNext').click(function(){
  $('.nav-item > a.nav-link.active').parent().next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
  $('.nav-item > a.nav-link.active').parent().prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```